# How to view Netlify unique deploy url in circleci directly from Github Pull request?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, devops, travis-ci, circleci

1. I want to view the [unique deployment URL of a Netlify build](https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/overview/) directly from my Github PR.
2. I currently use circelci for my continuous integration software. The current process is: click the circleci deploy details link > Scrolling to the bottom for the "Deploy netfliy" section > Copy the URL > open a new tab > paste URL into browser
3. Is there a way to make it so it's a one-click process

[This blog](https://sanderknape.com/2020/05/deploy-pull-requests-github-actions-deployments/) mentions [Github deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/delivering-deployments). But I'm not sure if that's the solution I want. Maybe it is? If it's the solution, how do I implement that in my current setup?

My goal is to keep my current CI and deployment services (i.e. not switch over from [Circelci](https://circleci.com/) to [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)), make minimal changes and keep things as simple as possible.

Bonus points if anyone can offer a solution that also works for other CI providers like [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/) (I use it for some of my open-source projects).

Here is the deployment code in my `.circleci/config.yml`:

```
name: Deploy Netlify
          command: |
            if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "master" ]; then
                echo 'deploying to prod';
                ./node_modules/.bin/netlify deploy --dir=./build --prod --site $NETLIFY_SITE_ID_PROD -m "${CIRCLE_BRANCH} ${CIRCLE_SHA1} ${CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST}"
            else
                echo 'deploying to staging';
                ./node_modules/.bin/netlify deploy --dir=./build --prod --site $NETLIFY_SITE_ID_STAGING -m "${CIRCLE_BRANCH} ${CIRCLE_SHA1} ${CIRCLE_PULL_REQUEST}"
```

### Step 1

[image: Step 1]

### Step 2

[image: Steps 2-N]